# Sharpness of the $1/6$-constant in the Cancellation Theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I originally posted this question over at Stackexchange, before realising it is much better suited for Overflow:

Let $\langle \; S \; | \; R \; \rangle$ be a presentation of a group $G$ with a set $R = R^{-1}$ of freely and cyclically reduced relators, and let $\Lambda$ be the girth of $\langle \; S \; | \; R \; \rangle$. Suppose that

1) the set $R$ of relators contains no proper power, and

2)  for any triple $x,y,z \in F(S)$ of reduced words, such that $yx$ and $zx$ are two distinct (reduced) cyclic conjugates of elements of $R$, we have $$|x| \leq 1/6 \Lambda,$$ where $|x|$ denotes the length of $x$.

Then, the famous **Cancellation Theorem** says that the corresponding *presentation complex* $P(S,R)$ is aspherical.

Does anybody know if (and why) the constant $1/6$ in the statement is sharp ?

To be more precise, I am not looking for an aspherical presentation that fails to meet condition $2$ (such are easy to construct). I am looking for a group with a non-aspherical presentation (in the above sense) that satisfies both conditions, but with constant $c > 1/6$.

Ideally, I am looking for an answer to the following question: For every $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist a presentation $P_{\epsilon}$ of a group $G_{\epsilon}$, satisfying both conditions, but with constant $1/6 + \epsilon$, such that $P_{\epsilon}$ is not aspherical ?

Comment: The dodecahedron.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Sure. Take a dodecahedron. Identify all the vertices. The result is a presentation complex which is clearly not aspherical, and where each 2-cell (ie relator) overlaps its neighbours in precisely 1/5 of its length.

Comment: This seems to be a very nice example. I just can't see why it is "clearly not aspherical". It the quotient map $\pi: S^2 \to D$ the "obvious" non-trivial element of the second homotopy ?

Comment: If $D\cong S^2$ is the dodecahedron (clearly non-aspherical, I hope), then the presentation complex $P=D/\sim$ is obtained by identifying the vertices of $D$, so we have a quotient map $\pi:D\to P$.  As I think you say, this defines the "obvious" non-trivial element of $\pi_2(P)$. There are various ways to see that it's non-trivial. For instance, the universal cover $\widetilde{P}$ is an infinite tree of copies of $D$, and $\pi$ lifts to an inclusion $\tilde{\pi}:D\hookrightarrow\widetilde{P}$.  There is also a retraction $\rho:\widetilde{P}\to D$. If $\pi$ were null-homotopic, by the...

Comment: ... Homotopy Lifting Lemma, $\tilde{\pi}$ would also be null-homotopic, and so, applying $\rho$ to the homotopy, we get that the identity map of $S^2$ is null-homotopic, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I didn't see that the universal cover $\tilde{P}$ ($D$ in my notation, but nevermind, yours is more appropriate) of $P$ is a infinite tree of copies of $D \cong S^2$. This is of course enough to see that $P$ is aspherical.

Comment: @HJRW but there exist numbers between $1/6$ and $1/5$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: that's why I only posted a comment (though it is the canonical example).   But it should now be clear that the problem is about finding certain cellular decompositions of the sphere.  I don't think it's terribly difficult (though I admit I haven't thought about it).

Comment: Following your argument, the $1/6$-Cancellation Theorem therefore also implies that there cannot exist a platonic solid such that each face is bounded by $k \geq 6$ edges :D.

Comment: @BerniWaterman -- that's right!  This is a standard application of the Euler characteristic of the sphere, which is closely related to how the 1/6 theorem is proved.

Comment: I seem to recall *Geometry of defining relations in groups* having references to this(maybe even Lyndon and Schupp), but I don't have my copy with me. "1/6" is the "start" of notions of flat curvature (tilling plane with hexagons)

Comment: I've just checked the very same book. It seems to be that, if $P$ satisfies the cancellation conditions for *any* $\lambda \in (1/6,1/5)$ (i.e, replacing $1/6$ by $\lambda$), then it is aspherical, since for any such $\lambda$, no relator $r \in R$ can be written as the product of less than $6$ pieces (this is the essential step in the proof). Moreover, if i understand correctly, *every* group  admits a presentation $P_{\lambda}$ satisfying (2) with $\lambda$ replacing $1/6$ for *any* $\lambda > 1/5$.